# Fitting data with Fourier Series coefficients

Tags: data-mining, statistics, loss-function

Suppose I have some data, given by $\boldsymbol{x}$ and $\boldsymbol{y}$ pairs, for instance$\{(\boldsymbol{x_1}, \boldsymbol{y_1}), (\boldsymbol{x_2},\boldsymbol{y_2}),...,(\boldsymbol{x_n},\boldsymbol{y_n})\}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

I assume that the data comes from some function $f(\boldsymbol{x})$ with some noise, I don't know the function, so we don't know whether it is periodic (very likely, it is NOT periodic).

This means $\boldsymbol{y_i} = f(\boldsymbol{x_i}) + \boldsymbol{\epsilon_i}$ where $\boldsymbol{\epsilon_i} \sim \textbf{N}(\textbf{0}, \boldsymbol{\sigma}^2))$.

Now I know that the Fourier Series is defined only for periodic functions. However ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/942740/fourier-series-for-a-non-periodic-function)) it is possible to "extend" a non-periodic function defined on an interval, to a periodic function.

The amount of data that I have is finite, so will lie in an interval.

So my question is:

> Does it make sense (is it even possible) to try and fit a Fourier Series to the data, by considering the data (which is multi-dimensional, both x and y are vectors) in a multi-dimensional interval , by finding the coefficients that minimize some loss function? (for instance Mean Squared Error)
>   How would someone define this fourier series for a multi-dimensional, non-periodic, noisy function?

(by using only a finite number of fourier terms!)

Comment: This is a standard approach in linear regression and should work OK for non-periodic functions. In general, you can choose a variety of [basis functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_function) and periodic basis functions can fit an interval (although they are also an obvious choice to fit a periodic target function).

Comment: @NeilSlater Thank you! Do you know of any package for python? At the moment I am trying something similar to method1 given here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23561856/fft-vs-least-squares-fitting-of-fourier-components

Comment: Sorry no I do not know a suitable library. Hopefully someone can give you a proper answer, all I have done is try to calm your worries in the comment. Basically, you are **not** attempting something unusual or without precedent

Comment: I agree with @NeilSlater. Rather than finding a package specific to this problem, it's possible to use a neural network framework like Keras and build a network where the input is your X values and the output is not Y, but instead coefficients (i.e. weights of your sinusoids) of a linear combination sinusoids. You'd need to build a custom loss function to compare the target with the predicted weighted (and shifted) sinusoids, but that is totally possible in Keras or Tensorflow in general.

Comment: @tom: It's even easier than that. Your input can be flattened [cos(x), cos(2x), cos(3x)] (where actual multiples of x chosen so that you get a sensible spread of frequencies over your interval). Then perform linear regression with those inputs. No neural network required.

Comment: @tom that is similar to what I was thinking! I have a couple of questions though. My first idea was to use the coefficients for the past 50 observations, as features to predict the next m observations. Would this work? Also, in your idea of using the coefficient as response: does it mean that I would have to fit a Fourier Series (with a finite number of coeff) to the whole training set, and then use those as response? But how would I do it with the teat set? I mean, maybe I am just getting confused, but if you could expand on that it would be great!!

Comment: @NeilSlater makes sense! But that would just be equivalent to fitting the NN to the data. Instead I think tom is proposing what to do after Ive fitted it to the data. But I am not sure